# ReactRouter communication between parent component and child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My parent component:

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            docked: false,
            open: false,
            transitions: true,
            touch: true,
            shadow: true,
            pullRight: false,
            touchHandleWidth: 20,
            dragToggleDistance: 30,
            currentUser: {}
        };

        this.renderPropCheckbox = this.renderPropCheckbox.bind(this);
        this.renderPropNumber = this.renderPropNumber.bind(this);
        this.onSetOpen = this.onSetOpen.bind(this);
        this.menuButtonClick = this.menuButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.updateUserData = this.updateUserData.bind(this);
    }
updateUserData(user){
        this.setState({
            currentUser: user
        })
    }
    render() { 
            return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div style={styles.content}>
                        <div className="content">
                            <Switch>

                                    <Route path="/login/:code/:state" component={Login} updateUserData = {this.updateUserData}/>
                                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Login}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
        }

    }
```

My child (login) component:

```
class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            linkedInUrl: ''
        };
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);

        if(query.get('code') && query.get('state')){
            const code = query.get('code');
            axios.post(Globals.API + '/user/saveUser', {
                code: code,
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.data.success == true){
                        this.props.updateUserData(response.data.user);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }

    }
render() {
        const { linkedInUrl } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="panel center-block" style={styles.panel}>
                <div className="text-center">
                    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" style={styles.logo}/>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <a href={linkedInUrl} className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
                        <span className="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                        Sign in with LinkedIn
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I am trying to update the currentUser object from `Main` component when I get a response in `Login` component and to also be able to access `currentUser` object from within all child components of `Main` (basically from my entire app). But `this.props` is empty in `Login` component and I cannot do `this.props.updateUserData(response.data.user);` either. Can anyone tell me why please? Thank you all for your time!

Comment: @TheReason How should I pass it? Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't pass any `props` to `Login` component. So to get it working you shouldn't use `component` prop on `Route` component. Instead of it you should use `render` prop, which takes a function which returns a component or jsx doesnt matter. More about `Route` component you can find [`here`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route).

So replace this route

```
<Route
  path="/login/:code/:state"
  component={Login}
  updateUserData = {this.updateUserData}
/>
```

To something like this, using `render` prop:

```
<Route
  path="/login/:code/:state"
  render={() => <Login updateUserData={this.updateUserData} currentUser= {this.state.currentUser} />}
/>
```

[`Worked example`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyrQaJ?editors=1010)

[`Here`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105) is more example how to pass props into `Route` components using react-router.

Hope it will help

Comment: I have tried it like this: <Route path="/login/:code/:state" render={() => <Login currentUser= {this.state.currentUser} updateUserData = {this.updateUserData}/>} /> and like this: <Route path="/login/:code/:state" render={() => <Login currentUser= {this.state.currentUser} }/>}  updateUserData = {this.updateUserData/> but in Login component I cannot access updateUserData nor am I receiving currentUser in props.

Comment: @Alphonse i updated my answer. Just copy and paste my route with props. It should work.

Comment: I have pasted it...sadly in Login this.props is still empty and I get the error in console with this.props.updateUserData is not a function